# Sharing Camera between Vuforia and WebRTC

Tags: android, android-camera, webrtc, vuforia

I am new to Vuforia and I am trying to integrate Qualcomm Vuforia on Android with WebRTC.

I couldnt find a way to do this but is it possible to share the camera stream between both the processes?

Or is sending Vuforia output stream to WebRTC the only way?

Thank you.